# How use swapDepths & getNextHighestDepth() in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to convert the following code:

```
DNA0.swapDepths(this.getNextHighestDepth())
```

I tried it this way:

```
DNA0.swapChildren(stage.getChildIndex(DNA0));
```

But its not working...
I guess I didn't understand the logic. Anybody help me?

----EDIT----
@gladoscc, good job. it's work. But I have other convert problems..

Like,

```
this['DNA'+DNAsy.length].y = this['DNA'+(DNAsy.length-1)].y;
this['DNA'+DNAsx.length].x = this['DNA'+(DNAsy.length-1)].x;
DNAsy.push(this['DNA'+DNAsy.length].y)
DNAsx.push(this['DNA'+DNAsx.length].x)
```

I guess, I will ask a new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DNA0.parent.setChildIndex( DNA0, DNA0.parent.numChildren -1 );
```

You can replace DNA0.parent with the DNA0 container reference:

```
cont.setChildIndex( DNA0, cont.numChildren -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring to front, just:

```
setChildIndex(myMC,numChildren – 1)
```