# Create new layer every time a button is clicked

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have the following code to allow the user to load an image onto the stage from their computer and this image is then placed into a new Sprite layer:

```
var imageBrowse:FileReference = new FileReference();

BrowseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, loadImage);
function loadImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    imageBrowse.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.png")]);
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
}

function fileSelected(e:Event):void{
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    imageBrowse.load();
    imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
    imageLayer.addChild(imageLoader);
    imageLoader.x = 375;
    imageLoader.y = 175;
    imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}
```

How would I go about coding it so that every time an image is uploaded (by clicking the `BrowseButton`) the image is added to a new `Sprite` layer (Perhaps `imageLoader1`, `imageLoader 2`, could be the names of the layers for exmaple). I'm just not sure how to loop through and create a new Sprite layer for each time an image is actually uploaded or if it's even possible.

Obviously the way I have it at the minute is that any uploaded image is placed onto the same layer and in the same place, meaning more than one image uploaded ends up with the images just stacked on top of each other as one 'image', unable to move them independently.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageBrowse:FileReference = new FileReference();
var myLoaders:Array = [];

BrowseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, loadImage);
function loadImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    imageBrowse.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.png")]);
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
}
function fileSelected(e:Event):void{
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    imageBrowse.load();
    //imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}
function imageLoaded(e:Event):void{
    //the length of the array is initially 0, so the first time it will be imageLoaders[0]
    //the intractive object needs to be a movieclip loader do not have start/stop drag methods
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length] = new MovieClip();//add clip to array
    //create a temporary loader
    var loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(e.target.data)
    //add the loader to the movieclip
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1].addChild(loader);
    //make the movieclip to the convention you specified
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length - 1].name = "imageLoader" + (myLoaders.length - 1).toString();
    //attach the moviclip to the imageLayer
    imageLayer.addChild(myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1]);
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1].x = 375;
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1].y = 175;
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onImageDown);
    myLoaders[myLoaders.length-1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onImageUp);
    imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}
function onImageDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //bring the image that you clicked to the top
    imageLayer.setChildIndex(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject, imageLayer.numChildren -1);
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
```

Comment: For the line that says `var imageLoaders:Array = [];` I get `1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbracket.`

Comment: Ah no, the error is for the line `var imageLoaders[imageLoaders.length] = new Loader();`

Comment: OK. I have updated it and I think that fixed it. It looks like the old array name (imageLoaders) was a reserved function in flash. That was throwing things off. Also note that I added a toString() method when naming the new loader.

Comment: Thanks but what happens now is that when I upload more than one image, the second image just overlays on top of the other one and I can't move them independently (using `startDrag` and `stopDrag`)

Comment: The issue is because the loader is being added to the `imageLayer` all the time rather than adding each loader image to a new layer, but I'm not sure how to add the loader to a new sprite layer that doesn't yet exist? I've declared the layers like: `var imageLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;` then added them by doing `addChild(imageLayer)`

Comment: Oh OK. I thought it was weird to put images on top of each other. So what you want to do is change child indexes of so that the object you click on and start dragging is always on top. There is an answer on how to do this on stack overflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678038/how-use-swapdepths-getnexthighestdepth-in-as3

Comment: How would that be applied to the code I have? I tried to put it in the  method used to drag the images around `dragImage`, which basically just says `imageLayer.startDrag();`. In the `dragImage` function I tried to do `imageLayer.setChildIndex(myLoaders, numChildren - 1);` but I get a syntax error. I'm probably doing something obvious wrong but I've never changed the indexes before so it's all a bit new to me.

Comment: I've been fiddling around and I just can't get it to work the way I want.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I did get back to you sooner. I have updated the code to something that I tested and know it works. I have posted an alternate answer if you do not need to keep track of the image objects in an array (its much cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of creating a "new layer" is to create a loader, then add it to a movie clip, to which you then add to your imageLayer object that can be the stage or a designate display object that you use as a canvas. To bring the selected object to the forefront you can change its index in the imageLayer to the highest available.

```
//create variables
var imageBrowse:FileReference = new FileReference();
var imageCount:int = 0;

BrowseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, loadImage);
function loadImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    imageBrowse.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.png")]);
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
}
function fileSelected(e:Event):void{
    imageBrowse.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    imageBrowse.load();
    //imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}
function imageLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var clip = new MovieClip();
    var loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(e.target.data)
    clip.addChild(loader);
    //make the movieclip to the convention you specified
    clip.name = "imageLoader" + (imageCount++).toString();
    //attach the moviclip to the imageLayer
    imageLayer.addChild(clip);
    clip.x = 375;
    clip.y = 175;
    clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onImageDown);
    clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onImageUp);
    imageBrowse.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}
function onImageDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //bring the image that you clicked to the top
    imageLayer.setChildIndex(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject, imageLayer.numChildren -1);
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
function onImageUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working; the second image I upload just goes on top of the first one in the same position and I can't move them individually; both images overlap each other and become one.

Comment: Obviously the way I have it at the minute is that any uploaded image is placed onto the same layer and in the same place, meaning more than one image uploaded ends up with the images just stacked on top of each other as one 'image', unable to move them independently.

Comment: OK. So if you want to move all the images together then omit adding the star/stop drag even listeners to the movie clips. Add the start/drop drag event listener to imageLayer (which should be a movieclip) and that should do it.

Comment: Do you have an email address I can contact you on? I think it would be best for you to see the code and run it (that's if you don't mind) so that you can see what I've done and what I want to do.